# Junit 5 with Spring Boot: When to use @ExtendWith Spring or Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I Have the following **abstract unit test class** that all my concrete unit test classes extend:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
//@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = PokerApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
public abstract class AbstractUnitTests {

    @MockBean
    public RoundService roundService;

    @MockBean
    public RoundRepository roundRepository;
}
```

What is the difference between using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`?

I ask as using either of the annotations seems to make no difference and both work respectively in my code - allowing me to use Junit5. So why do both work?

**Concrete test class:**

```
    @DisplayName("Test RoundService")
    public class RoundsServiceTest extends AbstractUnitTests {

        private static String STUB_USER_ID = "user3";

        // class under test
        @InjectMocks
        RoundService roundService;

        private Round round;

        private ObjectId objectId;

        @BeforeEach //note this replaces the junit 4 @Before
        public void setUp() {

            initMocks(this);
            round = Mocks.round();
            objectId = Mocks.objectId();
        }

        @DisplayName("Test RoundService.getAllRoundsByUserId()")
        @Test
        public void shouldGetRoundsByUserId() {

            // setup
            given(roundRepository.findByUserId(anyString())).willReturn(Collections.singletonList(round));

            // call method under test
            List<Round> rounds = roundService.getRoundsByUserId(STUB_USER_ID);

            // asserts
            assertNotNull(rounds);
            assertEquals(1, rounds.size());
            assertEquals("user3", rounds.get(0).userId());
        }
}
```

**Relevant Build.gradle section** :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**What is a Junit Extension**

The purpose of Junit 5 extensions is to extend the behavior of test classes or methods

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions)

Read on **Junit 5 Extension Model** & `@ExtendWith` annotation :[here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)

[`SpringExtension`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.html)

> SpringExtension integrates the Spring TestContext Framework into JUnit
>   5's Jupiter programming model.

```
public class SpringExtension
extends Object
implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, TestInstancePostProcessor, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback, ParameterResolver{..}
```

[`MockitoExtension`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.3.3/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html)

> This extension is the JUnit Jupiter equivalent of our JUnit4
>   MockitoJUnitRunner

```
public class MockitoExtension
extends java.lang.Object
implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver{..}
```

As it can be seen , `SpringExtension` implements a lot more extensions than `MockitoExtension`.

Also [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) is meta annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and which means every time your tests are extended with `SpringExtension`.
[`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) is a Spring test framework annotation and used along with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

To observe the difference try the following

`ExtendWith` only `MockitoExtension`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    TestService service;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(service); // Test will fail
    }

}
```

`ExtendWith` only `SpringExtension`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TestServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    TestService service;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(service); // Test succeeds
    }

}
```

`ExtendWith` with both `SpringExtension` and `MockitoExtension`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TestServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    TestService service;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(service); // Test succeeds
    }

}
```

Both works in your case because of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation for the test class as explained.

To answer the question : When to use `@ExtendWith` Spring or Mockito? ,

When the test requires a Spring Test Context ( to autowire a bean / use of `@MockBean` ) along with JUnit 5's Jupiter programming model use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. This will support Mockito annotations as well through TestExecutionListeners.

When the test uses Mockito and needs JUnit 5's Jupiter programming model support use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

Hope this helps

Comment: Should the use of `@InjectMocks` work in this context with Junit5?  I tried and got a wierd error.

Comment: @djangofan do post an SO question with reproducible test case

Comment: When to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` or `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: can we use mock up in @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) ?

Comment: You ever read something and think man I wish they wrote the docs like that.

Answer (score 19):

**When** to use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) or @SpringBootTest?

- When you use Integration test -@SpringBootTest annotation- or any slice test -@xxxTest annotations- you don't need @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) annotation since mentioned annotations include it.
- If you test @ConfigurationProperties, @Service, @Component  annotated class ( not defined in slice test cases - ref:Spring Boot Reference Document Testing/Auto-configured / SLICED Tests item-, you may use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) instead of @SpringBootTest.

Observation: I expect that a test with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) faster than the same test with @SpringBootTest.When I perform a test in Eclipse i observed the reverse.

Comment: In our case, we're using @SpringBootTest and passing in the specific configuration classes needed for the test. If we instead use only @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), it builds the entire application context, which of course takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

To add some extra information: I also recently figured out that if you use `@Mock` annotated dependencies in test class with `MockitoExtension` and you try to use `Mockito.when(mockedDependency.methodName())` in `@BeforeAll` setup method, then you are getting an `NullPointer` on your mocked dependency.

But if you change `MockitoExtension` to `SpringExtension`, it works fine. Looks like with `SpringExtension` mocked beans is initialized earlier (before `JUnit` launches `@BeforeAll` method) just like it should properly work.