# Application context is always null

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit5

I am using JUnit5, with sureFire version:

```
<maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
```

and code

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes =....ContextConfiguration.class)
    @TestPropertySource({"classpath:application-${env:dev}.properties", "classpath:app-${env:dev}.properties"})
    class TestRunner{
       @Test
       void testService(){
         BeanUtils.getBean(...);
       }
    }


@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext; // NOSONAR
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to manually autowire Spring Beans into classes that are not managed by Spring.
     *
     * @param beanClass - Class type of the required bean.
     **/
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

My ContextConfigurationClass has `@ComponentScan` directed to `BeanUtils` class, but the `ApplicationContext` is always null, not autowired.

I am using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` cuz i am also mocking in the test.

What `JUnit5`extension do i need to use in order to init it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SpringExtension`.

You could also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433806/junit-5-with-spring-boot-when-to-use-extendwith-spring-or-mockito) to understand the differences between `MockitoExtension` and `SpringExtension`

Comment: i am using mockito in this classes tho

Comment: That's fine.  You will still be able to mock your beans

Comment: hm, using SpringExtension will break most of the Beans that requires some data from property sources, they just wont get loaded thus bean creation fails