# Parent class' lateinit property has not been initialized in child's test

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to test class B's otherWork function but beacuse of its parent class' property I am getting `lateinit property p has not been initialized` error

```
class A{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var p:Propery
    
    fun work(){
        p.doSomething()
    }
}

class B:A{
    fun otherWork(){
        work()
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class Test{
    @MockkBean
    lateinit var p: Property

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup(){
        every { p.doSomething(any()) } returns Unit
    }
    
    @Test
    fun t(){
        /// tests
    }
}
```

The above approach didn't fix the issue. For my test A's work function is unimportant. How can I omit for the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is best explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433806/junit-5-with-spring-boot-when-to-use-extendwith-spring-or-mockito). In a nutshell, `@MockBean` and `@Autowired` are not processed by `MockitoExtension`. You need to use both `MockitoExtension` and `SpringExtension`:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
class Test { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly define the repeatable annotation `@Extensions`. From what I remember, earlier versions of Kotlin had some interoperability problems with Java's repeatable annotations, so this may be necessary:

```kotlin
@Extensions(
    ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class),
    ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
)
class Test { ... }
```